# How to create an Ajax Filter to display custom post types in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filter, custom-taxonomy

I asked a question to this topic before but since it seems like this requires just custom coding, I need help from the experts. I am not a coder, I design and build website in Webflow but want to learnt to convert them to a WordPress theme.

I have a Custom Post Type and want to display all of these posts on a page, however, above the displayed posts I want a filter, so that the user can click on a category and only see custom posts for that category (without page reload).

I registered a custom taxonomy and added categories for this. I see this on so many website, this seems to be a super common thing, and that's why I am so surprised that there is no plugin to achieve that. But anyway, here is an example of what I want to achieve: https://www.hauserlacour.de/en/work

I know that it has something to do with custom queries and AJAX. But I couldn't find a beginner friendly tutorial to achieve what I need.

Can anyone help me with the code below and what is needed to turn my custom taxonomy into a filter?

And here is the code I have as of now:

```
<?php get_header( 'page-posttest' ); ?>

<div class="projekte-wrapper-1">
    <?php $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'art',
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => false
    ) ) ?>


    <?php if( !empty( $terms ) ) : ?>

        <div class="taxonomy-wrapper">
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>" class="link" rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>


    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        $projekte_query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'projekte',
            'nopaging' => true,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'date'
        )
    ?>


    <?php $projekte_query = new WP_Query( $projekte_query_args ); ?>


    <?php if ( $projekte_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="posts-wrapper">
            <?php while ( $projekte_query->have_posts() ) : $projekte_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php PG_Helper::rememberShownPost(); ?>
                <?php $image_attributes = !empty( get_the_ID() ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( PG_Image::isPostImage() ? get_the_ID() : get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' ) : null; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="post w-inline-block" style="<?php if($image_attributes) echo 'background-image:url(\''.$image_attributes[0].'\')' ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <h1 class="heading-14"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> </a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'test' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer( 'page-posttest' ); ?>
```